# tau_exec unable to lantch, "error no matching binding for 'mpi'"

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, installation, mpi

I would like to use tau, I was not able to start tau_exec.When I try to use tau, I get error.

How I do to use tau?

-----Error--------

$ tau_exec -io ./a.out
Error: No matching binding for 'mpi' in directory /opt/tau/x86_64/lib
Available bindings (/opt/tau/x86_64/lib):
  /opt/tau/x86_64/lib/shared-disable
  /opt/tau/x86_64/lib/shared-papi-mpi-pthread-pdt-openmp-trace

I set following  environment variables.

TAU_MAKEFILE=/opt/tau/x86_64/lib/Makefile.tau-papi-mpi-pthread-pdt-openmp-trace
TAU_OPTIONS=-optCompInst

Install Pre-TAU

Configure and Install are following
./configure -c++=g++ -cc=gcc -fortran=gnu -mpilib=opt/openmpi/lib -mpiinc=/opt/openmpi/include   -prefix=opt/tau  -openmp   -iowrapper -papi=/opt/papi  -pthread
make install

Install PDT

./configure  -prefix=/opt/pdt
make
make install

Install After-TAU

./configure  -mpilib=/opt/openmpi/lib -mpiinc=/opt/openmpi/include -openmp  -iowrapper   -prefix=/opt/tau -pdt=/home/koji/opt/gauss07/tau/pdt -papi=/opt/papi -pthread
make install

Comment: Did you ever fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK with disabling MPI, try passing the `-T SERIAL` parameter to the tau_exec, ie. execute the application in a following way:

```
tau_exec -io -T SERIAL -- ./a.out
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the initial run failed is that default from the tau-config script (found on your system at /opt/tau/x86_64/bin/tau-config) sets profile, and not a trace, as the default action. In addition, it adds "trace" to the list of options that won't match. So the bindings that you want needs "mpi" and any binding that has "trace" will not work.

So, what you can do is try to build a new binding which has mpi and doesn't have trace, or try to run

```
tau_exec -io -T TRACE ./a.out
```

But then you will trace it and won't profile it.